# Alternatives of holding an instance of a class

Tags: java

I have an object which is essentially a data structure that has methods which need access to an instance of the 'Main' class (there can be multiple instances of this class). What I currently do is pass an instance of the main class in the constructor but this seems a bit clumsy. I could also pass an instance of the main class in the method call but this seems to add too much complexity and I would most likely also have the same problem as it is not always the main class that calls the methods.

I am not looking for static methods/variables as I am making changes to instance variables in the main class.

Are there any better ways to achieve this without having to store an instance in multiple places?

Example code:

```
public class Main {
    public Main() {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1(this);
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();

        class1.doSomething();
        class2.doSomething(this);
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        // There is a point to this... I swear...
    }
}

public class Class1 {
    private Main instance;

    public Class1(Main instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        instance.doSomethingElse();
    }
}

public class Class2 {
    public void doSomething(Main instance) {
        instance.doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem in storing instances of objects? You need a reference to an object to be able to call a method on this object. There's no way around it. What don't you like about what you have?

Comment: You want to act on multiple instances of multiple classes, and synchronizing the structures you access isn't sufficient?  Buy without referencing the instances you need to access? And in a multi-threaded environment, rendering thread locals useless?

Comment: I don't like storing information in every instance of a class, to me it seems a bit wasteful but as it seems necessary.

Comment: Well, it is necessary since you need a reference to the object to be able to call a method on it. You realize that a reference to an object is 4 bytes only, right? There are alternatices like using a more decoupled observer/observable pattern, or an event bus. But in the end, you'll always need references to objects.

Comment: Don't worry about wastefulness until you have a problem. Programming is all about clarity. Unless you create billions of them, references and even objects and are one of the cheapest things you can have (much cheaper than making copies of things).

Comment: I originally wrote the question to involve some multithreading but I later simplified and removed it but forgot to remove the tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about memory usage or rescourse management, take into account that even if you have 50 objects of your data-storge class, you will only need 1 instance of the Main class, and send this same instance to all your data-storage objects. The `Class1.instance` variable in your example will then point to the same instance of `Main` as `Class49.instance` etc. This is how pointers work and what makes them good.

You could make your data structure class extend the Main class, but other than that (excluding statics as you wish) there is no way around sending instances as parameters to constructors or methods.

Answer (score 1):

To judge what is better, always look for what the reader of the code expects.

First of all there is the matter of 'has a' relationship. If you say `Class1` is always interested in the same `Main` instance. And at all times it makes sense for this connection to be there (so at all times `Class1` could sensibly call methods in `Main`). Then `Class1` is the better choice.

In other cases you can argue: `Class2` provides a service, based on whatever instance of `Main` is passed. Then this is the better choice.

In your example both `Class1` and `Class2` instances are shortlived. In that case I assume they have no state, and I would go for passing the instance of `Main` to the function. This is functionally equivalent to a static method, however, by doing it with on an instance of a stateless object, you keep your options open for future expansion and testing. An example expansion for me was that I later added 'settings' for my helper class (`Class2` in your example), these settings were active across all functions on the helper class.

Comment: I probably should have added more information to the question: The objects would most likely be relatively short lived and stored in a medium sized array (several thousand of them) they will most likely be made immutable as it is designed to be thread safe. Is Class1 still a good fit for this?

Comment: The amount of objects is irrelevant for your numbers. The thread safety can be done by both solutions. As `Class1` and `Class2` are immutable, the data changes will be done to main, that needs to be a threadsafe class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the singleton pattern or an extension of this pattern could be what you need? The objects (instances from Class1 or Class2) would access Main.getInstance() to receive the/an instance of the Main class (the singleton pattern can be extended in order to support only a limited amount of instances instead of just exactly one).

Comment: While the Singleton pattern would achieve what the question is looking for, most people seem to think that the way he is doing it now is better.  Passing the instance to every object that needs it allows more flexibility in the face of potential future changes that may (for example) require two instances, or allows passing a test double for the purposes of unit testing without having complex full implementations of everything hanging around.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the *maintenance* overhead of having to pass the Main class instance (and potentially other instances later as the program grows) around every time, then maybe what you're looking for is a dependency injection framework (what you're doing at the moment is dependency injection; a dependency injection framework is intended to automate the process).  Spring is the best known, but there are others.  It's probably only worth it if you expect the project to get large (there's a pretty big overhead involved in getting to know how to use such a framework), but it would simplify the task of ensuring that all objects have references to everything they need.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are after, but you could use an inner class (non-static). It has an invisible reference (Main.this), so resource-wise there is no difference but you don't have to pass in a reference explicitly.

```
    public class Main {
        public Main() {
            Class1 class1 = new Class1();
            class1.doSomething();
        }

        public void doSomethingElse() {
        }

        public class Class1 {
            public void doSomething() {
                doSomethingElse();
            }
        }
    }
```